# excel merge cell data, based on conditions, multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file, which came out of two files, i copied everything from the second file, to the first. The task needed to be accomplished, is the following: for each row (actually for each id, stored in column A - which came from excel 1 ) that the following condition is true:

column E(which came from excel 1) = column B(which came from excel 2) AND column C(which came from excel 1) = column D(which came from excel 2),

then i must insert data from column Z(which came from excel 2) and column Y (which came from excel 2) to column X(which came from excel 1).

If column X, has already data in it, all new inserted data must have | as a separator, and should be inserted in front of the existing value.

If no data exist in column Z, or Y, then nothing is inserted to column X.

I have tried without success, to use index match, but no luck, i think something more complicated is needed. How can i do this with an excel formula? 
How the below formula should be transformed, in order to get the row that 
fulfils the conditions?
=X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D2),Sheet2!Z2 & "|" & Sheet2!Y2,"")

=X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D:D),Sheet2!Z#lineWHICHMATCHESCRITERIA & "|" & Sheet2!Y#lineWHICHMATCHESCRITERIA,"")

Comment: if you already have data in Col X you cannot add a formula in it. You will need to create a new column to get data from X and Y & Z from the other excel if your conditions are met. Also, it would be easier to understand if instead of excel1 and excel2 you used Sheet1 and Sheet2. Meaning you already had data in sheet 1 and copied data from excel 2 to sheet2

Comment: actually, in order to make things easier, i have both excel files merged into one. I have copied everything from excel #2 into excel #1. Then i guess, the formula should be inserted into a blank cell, and it should merge three columns' data, but with which formulas?

Comment: If your data is in 2 sheets, this formula should work in some empty cell in the same row `=X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D2),Sheet2!Z2 & "|" & Sheet2!Y2,"")`. If you have have appended the data to the end of excel1 data, then need to know the last row to change this formula

Comment: i will try this formula, i prefer to have the two excel files in two separate sheets, it is best practice, i thought working on one sheet would be easier... I will let you know of the result.

Comment: You can use this trick. Move your excel 2 data to sheet2. use the formula. then cut the sheet2 data and paste in sheet1. the formula will be updated :P

Comment: with this formula, we search in a particular row in sheet 2. The task is to look the entire column B, and D, B:B, D:D, then find the exact row that column E= column B AND column C = column D, then from the row that we found a match from sheet 2, take the data we need and merge them to the new column that needs to be created in sheet 1. So we must also search the whole sheet 2, and not only line 2